# Sharepoint 2013 Branding and userinterface Learning

Tags: branding

i searched for some source of sharepoint 2013 branding learning and i couldn't find anything which teaches Comprehensively!
if you know any with applied examples please tell me
best.

Comment: What is "user interface learning" and how does it relate to branding? What do you mean by branding? What's the nature of your goal? Publishing site? Collaboration? You need to be more specific.

Comment: i mean some resource for customizing master pages and css in sharepoint 2013

Comment: i'm intrested in pdf files for this learning